# Using PHP with Google Base and general feed questions

Tags: php, api, rss

So I've been looking into using google base for a clients job listing project. Are there any good tutorials on using PHP and curl to interact with the google base API? I was having trouble finding one on google.  I attempted to cURL to the following URL: http://www.google.com/base/feeds/snippets?bq=digital+camera and working with the XML, but it didn't seem to be properly formatted XML.

I'm pretty new to dealing with feeds although I've used simpleXML and DOMDocument quite a bit so I figure this won't be too hard.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [here.](http://code.google.com/apis/base/samples/php/php-sample.html)

Comment: This seems to only show how to add data to google base and query your own data.  In my understanding, I should be able to cURL to a particular URL using specific attributes for my search to return very specific results, I just can't find out how to structure these queries.